# What is the difference between the [speaking] and [spoken-language] tags supposed to be?

Tags: discussion, tags, ambiguous-tags

At the time of writing, [speaking](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speaking) has 21 questions, and [spoken-language](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spoken-language) has 17 questions. Looking through those questions, I can't seem to tell why one would choose one of the tags over the other (besides typing "speak" versus "spoke" into the tag-selection box). The tag wikis don't seem to help me disambiguate these, either.

Should there be a difference between these two tags (and if so, what?), or should one be synonymized to the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the tag wiki descriptions, there doesn't seem to be any difference.  I suggest we keep [spoken-language](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spoken-language).

However, not everything tagged [speaking](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speaking) should be merged into [spoken-language](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spoken-language), as it seems some would be better under something like [pronunciation](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronunciation), [pitch-accent](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pitch-accent) or similar.

In most cases questions under [speaking](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speaking) appear to have have other appropriate tags already attached, so perhaps the best thing to do would be to remove [speaking](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speaking) from those questions, then make [speaking](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speaking) a synonym of [spoken-language](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spoken-language).

As there aren't that many questions, I'm happy to run through the list and do some retag edits if the rest of the community agree to this plan.

Comment: Sounds good to me!

Comment: I've snipped a couple out (mostly ones that were really pronunciation questions) - don't want to go overboard and swamp the active questions list with retag edits too much.

Comment: I edited a few more.  I'll come back in a few days and do that again so it doesn't get swamped, like you said.

Comment: I merged the remaining few questions into [tag:spoken-language].